# python turtle creating flickering images when using tracer(0,0)

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am trying to make a program that will repeatedly draw two lines. my code is

```
import turtle

screen = turtle.Screen()
t = turtle.Turtle()
t.hideturtle()
t.speed(0)
screen.tracer(0,0)

while True:
    screen.clear()
    t.penup()   
    t.goto(1,12)
    t.pendown()
    t.goto(4,67)
    t.penup()
    t.goto(50, 3)
    t.pendown()
    t.goto(4, 73)
    screen.update()
```

I expect this to show two lines in turtle which do not flicker. however it is drawing one line and that line is flickering. the lines do need to be redrawn every frame so i can do some other stuff with the lines. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: don't do `screen.clear()`, instead do `t.clear()`.

When you clear the screen, you reset a number of its properties to the default values, including the `tracer()` setting.  You simply want to clear whatever the turtle drew in the last iteration so clear the turtle instead.

In the long term, you don't want `while True:` in an event-driven environment like turtle.  I would write this code more like:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def one_step():
    turtle.clear()

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(1, 12)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.goto(4, 67)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(50, 3)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.goto(4, 73)

    screen.update()
    screen.ontimer(one_step, 50)

screen = Screen()
screen.tracer(False)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()

one_step()

screen.mainloop()
```